# Replace an old distribution with a newer one alongside Windows

Tags: partition, system-installation, boot-loader, shared-partition

About 1 year ago, I installed Kali Linux alongside Windows 7. I made 2 primary partition (`ntfs`) and an extended partition for `Linux`. The first ntfs partition is used to install Windows 7, the other one is a big shared partition for general purpose data. The extended one contains 3 logical partitions : one for `/` (ext4, also contains grub boot-loader), the other for `/home` (ext4) & the last is a `swap`.

After some time of using Linux, I started feeling that I was using the wrong distribution. Moreover, it started to have a lot of errors, so I wanted to get ride of it -- but I want to keep the 2 `ntfs` partitions and Linux's `/home` partition untouched.

What are the precautions I need to take in consideration in order not to lose the `/home` partition and keep Windows installed alongside the new distribution (boot-loader precautions)?

The current Linux distribution is 32-bits & I am going to replace it with 64-bits Debian 9 (stretch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you got any experience in manual partitioning during a Linux distro installation? If so, what is the problem? Just choose manual and set to format and reuse the / partition.

If you specify what distro you're going to install, I can be more precise on instructions, and maybe provide a sort or guide or how to.

Remember the device node so you can reinstall grub at the end of the installation.

Just to better reply your question: "what are the precautions...".

**Have multiple and proven and reliable backups!**

**Edit #1**
[debian forums](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=48373) take a look at paivakil's first reply. It's all you need to do, even if it's an old post. Debian setup didn't changed in this part.

**Edit #2**
Please take [debian handbook](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.installation-steps.html) as best reference, at the "Manual partitioning" chapter. 
You need to find the / partition where you have Kali installed, and set the manual partitioner the following:

- format partition (optionally change fs etc)
- mount point /

Then go to the /home partition and just set mount point /home. Leave the home partition unaltered. Leave Windows partitions unaltered.

If you do something wrong with the partitioner, don't panic! You haven't damaged anything until you do **"Save changes to the disks".**

Comment: I am going to replace Kali with Debian 9 (stretch).